# JavaScript, the use replace

Tags: javascript

```
var text_source="<a href='c:/exam_file.xls' target='_blank'>file downdload</a>";
text_search="file";
text_source.replace(new RegExp(text_search, 'gi'), 
                   "<span style='font-weight:bold'>" +
                   text.toLowerCase() + "</span>");
```

The "a tag" link address has also changed:

```
<a href="C:/exam_<span style='font-weight:bold'>"file</span>"><span style='font-weight:bold'>file</span> download</a>
```

But, It should look like this. I have to change the text value in the "a tag".

```
<a href="C:/exam_file.xls" target="_blank"><span style='font-weight:bold'>file</span> download</a>
```

Comment: You should not use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: Does your example show the actual situation because if so the solution is quite simple. Only run the regex on the inner content of the anchor.

Comment: @baris - They are blindly quoting something they've read without giving any context. Just ignore it for now.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I'm not blindly quoting anything.  Please, there is no need to be uncivil.

Comment: @Daedalus - I'm not trying to be uncivil. Your statement muddies the water when a programmer is still learning to solve basic problems. Try explaining how HTML is not a regular language and unsuitable for robust regular expressions to a new programmer so it doesn't scare them off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address what I said in a second, but you can do this without a loop with just pure regex.  Below is how I accomplished this:

```
var text_source = "<a href='c:/bilmem_ne_dosyasi.xls' target='_blank'>Dosya Downdload</a>";
text_search = "dosya";
var patt = new RegExp("(<a .*?>)(" + text_search + ")(.*?</a>)","gi");
var text_source = text_source.replace(patt, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + "<span style='font-weight:bold'>" + $2.toLowerCase() + "</span>" + $3;
});
document.write(text_source);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/89REV/)**
​

Getting back to what I said earlier, however, html can be a very, very complex language, and although regex *can* be used to parse it, partially, it should not be used for large quantities of data.  Some patterns are too intricate to match against.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your RegExp runs only against the content of the elements, you will need to select all of the elements that you want to manipulate and check their contents.

As an example:

```
var regExp = /dosya/ig;
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 0).forEach(function(element) {
  if(regExp.test(element.textContent)) {
    element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(regExp, function(text) {
      return '<span style="font-weight: bold">' + text.toLowerCase() + '</span>';
    })
  }
});
```

There is also a jQuery pseudo selector [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) that does a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the replies about not using regexes with HTML or XML are on the whole, correct, you could use the following for simple cases where you don't have too many nested tags:

```
var text_source="<a href='c:/bilmem_ne_dosyasi.xls' target='_blank'>Dosya Downdload</a>";
text_search="(<[^>]*>[^<]*)(dosya)([^<]*<[^>]*>)";
var replaced = text_source.replace(new RegExp(text_search, 'gi'), "$1<span style='font-weight:bold'>$2</span>$3");
```